# How to convert an arbitrarily large duration to a nanosecond precision duration without overflows?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

Suppose I have my own clock with same epoch as `system_clock`:

```
using namespace std;

struct myclock
{
    using rep = int64_t;
    using period = nano;
    using duration = chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = chrono::time_point<myclock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady = chrono::system_clock::is_steady;

    static time_point now() noexcept;
};
```

I need to convert any `tp` (of type `system_clock::time_point`) into `myclock::time_point` like this:

1. (if need be) truncate `tp` to discard "past-nanosecond" precision
2. if `tp.time_since_epoch()` is in `myclock::time_point`s valid range -- return `myclock::time_point() + tp.time_since_epoch()`
3. otherwise, throw an exception

But, without knowing `system_clock`s `period` and `rep` I am running into [integer overflows](https://godbolt.org/z/hd6E97):

```
    constexpr auto x = chrono::duration<int64_t, milli>(numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
    constexpr auto y = chrono::duration<int8_t, nano>(1);

    constexpr auto z1 = x / nanoseconds(1) * nanoseconds(1);   // naive way to discard post-nanosecond part
    constexpr auto z2 = y / nanoseconds(1) * nanoseconds(1);
    static_assert( x > y );
```

How to write this logic in such way that it works reliably for any `tp` and arbitrary `system_clock::period/rep`?

P.S. I checked MSVC's implementation of `duration_cast`/`time_point_cast`, but it seems that they have same problem (or require same clock type).

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just convert the time point to nanoseconds via `duration_cast`? Why doesn't that work? "*without knowing system_clocks period and rep*" But you do know it's `period` and `rep`; they're members of `system_clock`. It may change from implementation to implementation, but it will be fixed for any given implementation.

Comment: @NicolBolas It looks like sufficiently large values result in overflows and incorrect result. See godbolt link in the post.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in that example you are trying to convert 2^63 ms to nanoseconds. Apart from the overflow issue which is of course guaranteed to happen, does this duration make any sense? 2^63 ms is 290000000 years. Do you seriously think anyone has a clock with that much precision?

Comment: What is "past-nanosecond" precision? You mean like picoseconds? `x` is already in milliseconds, I'm not sure what the goal here is.

Comment: well I am not familiar with chron much. but why not to use double std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano> t=x;

Comment: @C.M.: And what about `period` and `rep`? Those are part of `system_clock`, so if you're trying to convert from a `system_clock::time_point`, you have access to them.

Comment: @Barry If `x` is in milliseconds then no truncation is needed

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5EhTPf

Comment: @NicolBolas I am having difficulties writing logic that handles arbitrary `system_clock` `period` and `rep` generically

Comment: @qwr `double` can't represent every `int64_t`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It is about writing a correct generic code for converting from time with arbitrary precision to time with another (pre-defined) precision. It doesn't matter here if it is nano- or mili-.

Comment: You cannot write correct generic code that operates with integers larger than 2^64-1, with or without std::chrono. Unless you use a bignum package of some sort of course. Your example demonstrates this, only this, and nothing else. If you want unlimited integers, you need a bignum package. If you don't want a bignum package, you need to limit the range of your numbers. It's that simple.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Pretty sure I did it (for subset of cases that I care about). See my answer to this post -- I'd appreciate another set of eyes checking it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Check out my answer below, it should explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Barry Check out my answer below, it should explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So you are now doing limited-range checked/safe arithmetic, instead of limited-range unchecked/unsafe arithmetic. That's absolutely wonderful. I cannot find any obvious flaws in your implementation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.Yes, that is what I was trying to do... Maybe my question wasn't clear enough (too specific?)? Plus, Nicol edited the title to more generic (and yet more confusing) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** code update to deal with some `if constexpr`-related quirks.

Here is what I came up with ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TxjGjj)):

```
template<class Dx, class Dy>
constexpr Dx conv_limit()   // noexcept //C++20: change this into consteval
{
    // Notes:
    //  - pretty sure this works only for non-negative x (for example because of integer promotions in expressions used here)

    using X  = typename Dx::rep;
    using Rx = typename Dx::period;
    using Y  = typename Dy::rep;
    using Ry = typename Dy::period;
    using Rxy = ratio_divide<Rx, Ry>;               // y = x * Rxy, Rxy = Rx / Ry

    constexpr X xmax = numeric_limits<X>::max();
    constexpr Y ymax = numeric_limits<Y>::max();

    static_assert(numeric_limits<X>::is_integer);
    static_assert(numeric_limits<Y>::is_integer);

    static_assert(xmax > 0);                        // sanity checks
    static_assert(ymax > 0);
    static_assert(Rxy::num > 0);
    static_assert(Rxy::den > 0);

    if constexpr (Rxy::num == 1)                    // y = x / Rxy::den
    {
        static_assert(Rxy::den <= xmax);            // ensure Rxy::den fits into X

        // largest x such that x / Rxy::den <= ymax
        constexpr X lim = [&]() -> X {             // have to use lambda to avoid compiler complaining about overflow when this branch is unused
            if (xmax / Rxy::den <= ymax)
                return xmax;
            else
                return ymax * Rxy::den + (Rxy::den - 1);
        }();

        // if (x <= lim) --> y = static_cast<Y>(x / static_cast<X>(Rxy::den));
        return Dx(lim);
    }
    else if constexpr (Rxy::den == 1)               // y = x * Rxy::num
    {
        static_assert(Rxy::num <= ymax);            // ensure Rxy::num fits into Y

        // largest x such that x * Rxy::num <= Ymax
        constexpr X lim = (xmax < ymax ? xmax : ymax) / Rxy::num;

        // if (x <= lim) --> y = static_cast<Y>(x) * static_cast<Y>(Rxy::num);
        return Dx(lim);
    }
    else
        static_assert(!sizeof(Dy*), "not implemented");
}
```

this function returns maximum value of duration `Dx` that can be safely converted to duration `Dy`, if following conditions hold:

- `Dx::rep` and `Dy::rep` are integers
- `Dx` value is non-negative
- conversion ratio is trivial (either `num` or `den` is `1`)

Using this now it is possible to write a safe conversion function:

```
template<class Dy, class Dx>
constexpr Dy safe_duration_cast(Dx dx)
{
    if (dx.count() >= 0 && dx <= conv_limit<Dx, Dy>())
    {
        using X  = typename Dx::rep;
        using Rx = typename Dx::period;
        using Y  = typename Dy::rep;
        using Ry = typename Dy::period;
        using Rxy = ratio_divide<Rx, Ry>;

        if constexpr (Rxy::num == 1)
            return Dy( static_cast<Y>(dx.count() / static_cast<X>(Rxy::den)) );
        else if constexpr (Rxy::den == 1)
            return Dy( static_cast<Y>(dx.count()) * static_cast<Y>(Rxy::num) );
    }

    throw out_of_range("can't convert");
}
```

**Notes:**

- pretty sure everything under the `if` can be replaced with simple `duration_cast<Dy>(dx)`, but after checking MSVC's implementation I prefer mine.
- now it is trivial to write a safe conversion between clocks (if they share same epoch):

  `c1::time_point() + safe_duration_cast<c1::duration>(c2::now().time_since_epoch())`
- ... and if epochs differ all that is needed is an offset and additional check (to avoid wraparounds)

This is already enough for me -- on all platforms (that I care about) `system_clock` satisfies my requirements.

But it is curious to analyze case of non-trivial `Rxy` -- in this case (mathematically):

`y = x * Rxy = x * n // d`, where:

- `//` means "whole-number division" (i.e. `7 // 2 = 3`)
- n and d belong to N (natural numbers, i.e. `1,2,3,...`)
- `gcd(n,d) == 1` (to help with overflows in calculations)

The trick would be to write a generic code that will perform said calculation on any platform for maximum range of values. Optionally one can elect to fail on certain class of values for the sake of performance (e.g. if given platform has `bignum`, we could choose to ignore it and perform calcs using primitive types).

There are multiple aspects here to consider:

- for sufficiently small `x` you can simply run this calc (potentially using `comon_type_t<X,Y>` or `intmax_t` for intermediate calcs)
- calc can be rewritten as: `y = x // d * n + (x % d) * n // d`, in which case figuring out if given `x` is safe to convert becomes non-trivial (e.g. if `X` is `int8_t` and `Rxy = 99/100` then only `0,1,100,101` can be safely converted without using wider integer type (which may not exist)). Note that using unsigned type can widen our safe class of values (doing this in `uint8_t` adds `2` and `102` to the list)
- some implementation (instead of pre-calculating `safe values`) may use hardware flags (i.e. if given multiplication overflows -- it will set the some CPU flag, which will lead to `out_of_range` being thrown)
- I bet doing this with floating point `rep` type could be interesting
- dropping `x has to be non-negative` requirement could be interesting too...

**Additional notes**

- it would be nice if C++ provided similar tools to ensure safe conversions
- using `std::ratio` is cool, but it hides overflows -- normally I rely on compiler to warn me about possible issues, `std::ratio` breaks this. You can easily run into very [surprising behaviour](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cZndIK8BLNY7jZNw) and you wouldn't know it until your program encounters such value long after you forgot about it... Especially, if values are retrieved from outside (file time stamps/etc)

Comment: This seems reasonable to me.  In essence you've implemented a subset of a "safe int" class such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/safeint/safeint-library?view=vs-2019 .  You could also just re-use a fully implemented safe-int library as the `rep` in the `duration`.

Comment: Oh, one thing to be aware of.  chrono itself uses `duration_cast` internally, for example for implicit conversions and comparisons.  It won't call your `safe_duration_cast`.  So you'll need to use your `conv_limit` to make those operations overflow-proof as well.  This is where a safe-int lib would be superior as it would also cover those cases.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `you've implemented a subset of a "safe int" class` -- kind of... I've implemented a "safe-with-respect-to-given-transformation class", where transformation is `std::chrono::duration` conversion, which itself depends on (known-at-compile-time) values of respective `num` and `den`. I didn't cover most interesting case of non-trivial Rxy, but it will be enough for my needs (which is `system_clock` <--> `myclock` conversion). And `myclock` is basically a way to deal with file-system time on Linux (and NFS servers) without truncation (that is why I need to handle any value)

Comment: *correction: "without truncation" -> "without overflows". If system_clock has higher precision than nanosecond -- this logic will truncate it to nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you divide this problem into two pieces:

1. Convert any precision `time_point<myclock, D>` to/from `time_point<system_clock, D>`, while preserving the precision `D`.
2. Write a free function (say `checked_convert`) to convert from one precision to another (within the same `time_point` clock family) with throw on overflow.

### First conversion of `time_point`s among clocks:

Add static member functions `to_sys` and `from_sys` to `myclock` like this:

```
struct myclock
{
    using rep = std::int64_t;
    using period = std::nano;
    using duration = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<myclock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady = std::chrono::system_clock::is_steady;

    static time_point now() noexcept;

    template<typename Duration>
    static
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>
    to_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<myclock, Duration>& tp)
    {
        using Td = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;
        return Td{tp.time_since_epoch()};
    }

    template<typename Duration>
    static
    std::chrono::time_point<myclock, Duration>
    from_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>& tp)
    {
        using Td = std::chrono::time_point<myclock, Duration>;
        return Td{tp.time_since_epoch()};
    }
};
```

Now you can convert to `system_clock` like this:

```
myclock::time_point tp;
auto tp_sys = myclock::to_sys(tp);
```

or go the other way with `myclock::from_sys`.

The cool thing about doing this is that when you migrate to C++20 some time in the future, you can change your syntax to:

```
auto tp_sys = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(tp);
tp = std::chrono::clock_cast<myclock>(tp_sys);
```

And even cooler, with no further changes to your code, you can also `clock_cast` to/from:

1. `utc_clock`
2. `tai_clock`
3. `gps_clock`
4. `file_clock`

The `clock_cast` system will use your `to_sys`/`from_sys` to bounce off of `system_clock` to/from any of these other `std`-defined clocks, or even to another user-defined clock that has opted into the `to_sys`/`from_sys` system.

### Second:  checked conversion

```
template <class Duration, class Clock, class DurationSource>
std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>
checked_convert(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, DurationSource> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using Tp = time_point<Clock, Duration>;
    using TpD = time_point<Clock, duration<long double, typename Duration::period>>;
    TpD m = Tp::min();
    TpD M = Tp::max();
    if (tp < m || tp > M)
        throw std::runtime_error("overflow");
    return time_point_cast<Duration>(tp);
}
```

The idea here is to temporarily convert to floating point based time_points for the overflow check.  You could also use a 128 bit integral `rep`.  Just anything with a ridiculously high min/max.  Do the check.  Throw on overflow.  And if safe, then convert to the desired integral `rep`.

```
sys_time<microseconds> tp1 = sys_days{1600y/1/1};
auto tp2 = checked_convert<nanoseconds>(tp1);  // throws "overflow"
std::cout << tp2 << '\n';
```

(I've used C++20 syntax to construct system_clock-based time_points above)

One may ask:  Why isn't `checked_convert` supplied by the standard?

*Answer:*  Because it isn't perfect.  The precision of your `long double` may (or may not) be less than the precision of your integral `rep` underlying the `time_point`.   A better choice would be a 128 bit integral `rep` which will definitely have sufficient precision.  But some platforms don't have 128 bit integral types.  Even some platforms (low level embedded) may not even have floating point types.  So there's not a good standards solution for this problem at this time.  And there are several techniques available to the client, including the [one in this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63125127/576911).

### Update

Here's a `duration` version of `checked_convert`:

```
template <class Duration, class Rep, class Period>
Duration
checked_convert(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using D = duration<long double, typename Duration::period>;
    D m = Duration::min();
    D M = Duration::max();
    if (d < m || d > M)
        throw std::runtime_error("overflow");
    return duration_cast<Duration>(d);
}
```

When used like this it throws an exception:

```
constexpr auto x = duration<int64_t, milli>(numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
constexpr auto y = duration<int8_t, nano>(1);
auto z = checked_convert<decltype(y)>(x);
```

Comment: this suffers from floating point precision issues when close to the boundary, >= would be more conservative.

Comment: You're right.  But there are several imperfect fixes.  I've elaborated on this in my answer.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I don't think this works for me. It looks like this can't handle every possible input value correctly. In fact, this is dangerous - you end up with a seemingly correct code that compiles fine, but produces unexpected results for a class of values (instead of throwing or producing warnings during compilation). [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cZndIK8BLNY7jZNw) is a very simple example.

Comment: What I am trying to say is: I know how to write such logic for any specific `system_clock::rep` and `system_clock::period` -- said logic will take care of all possible overflows/etc. But I can't figure out how to write such logic generically -- i.e. for any (class of) `system_clock::rep` and `period` and using existing library facilities (duration_cast/etc) leads to incorrect code (it seems).

Comment: The `checked_convert` will handle the `milliseconds` to `nanoseconds` `time_point` conversion you allude to.  Or are you saying that you would like a `duration`-version of `checked_convert`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant It is not directly related to a problem being discussed, but try compiling `checked_convert<decltype(x)>(y)` -- it fails for me.

Comment: You'll have to use `checked_convert<duration<int64_t, milli>>(y)` instead.  gcc's implementation of `<chrono>` is choking on the `const` qualifier on `x`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant What do you think about my solution? (see my answer to this post)